# Question about covering spaces concerning a one-sheeted covering map

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I have a general question about covering spaces and covering maps.  If $f$ is a one sheeted covering map of $X$, then is or is it not true that $X$ is homeomorphic to $X$?

Answer (score 1):

It's true. A covering map is by definition continuous. Since it is one-sheeted, it is a bijection. Since it is a local homeomorphism, the inverse map of sets is in fact continuous. Specifically, given any open set $U$, let $\{U_x\}_{x \in X}$ be the collection of neighborhoods of $x \in U$ for which the covering map is a local homeomorphism. Then $\{U_x \cap U\}_{x \in X}$ is a collection of open sets covering $U$, and ${h(U_x \cap U)}_{x \in X}$ is a collection of open sets whose union is $h(U)$. This shows that $h^{-1}$ sends $U$ to an open set $h(U)$, so is continuous.

(Note the "local homeomorphism" assumption is important--there exist continuous bijections that are not homeomorphisms.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it was already answered. But you have other ways of proving this statement.
If $p:E\to B $ is a one sheeted covering, we can prove that this is morphism isomorphic to a homeomorphism - therefore it is a homeomorphism.
Not that $p_*(\pi _1(E,e))=\pi _1(B,p(e))$ because the index of $p_*(\pi _1(E,e))$ in $\pi _1(B,p(e)) $ is $1$.

Take the identity $Id_B$. This map is obviously a covering (which is a homeomorphism). Now, look at the fact that this identity induces the same subgroup of $ \pi _1(B,b) $.
Explicitly, $ Id_{B_*} (\pi _1(B,b)) = p_*(\pi _1(E,e)) $ . So $p$ is isomorphic to $Id_B $.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p:\tilde X\to X$ be a 1-sheeted covering map. For any evenly covered open subset $U$ of $X$, let us denote $p^{-1}(U)$ by $\tilde U$. Then the restriction of $p$ to $\tilde U$ gives a homeomorphism $\tilde U\to U$.

Suppose $a,b\in \tilde X$ such that $p(a)=p(b)=x\in X$. Let $U$ be an evenly covered open subset of $X$ which contains $x$. As $a,b\in \tilde U$, it follows that $a=b$. So we see that $p$ is injective.

Let $x\in X$ and $U$ be an evenly covered open subset of $X$ containing $x$. As $p(\tilde U)=U$, it follows that there exists $\tilde x\in \tilde X$ such that $p(\tilde x)=x$. This shows that $p$ is onto.

So $p:\tilde X\to X$ is a continuous bijection. It remains to show that $p^{-1}:X\to \tilde X$ is continuous. Let $x\in X$ and $U$ be an evenly covered open subset of $X$ which contains $x$. Then the restriction of $p^{-1}$ to $U$ is continuous as it is the inverse of the homeomorphism from $\tilde U\to U$ given by the restriction of $p$ to $\tilde U$.